# return text value based on max date available

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a "date" table and a table called Grade (sample table below):

[image]

I want to count the TAGIDs in each grade based on the date selected from the date table. Suppose I select 30-11-2018 I should get 2 counts for grade A one for TAGID 1 and another count for tagid 2. I should get 1 count for B grade and that will be the count for TAGID 3. 
More explanation:
TAGID 3 has 2 grade in November but only the maximum date will be considered which is grade B. So there will be no count of Grade D id 30-11-2018 is selected.

Basically, I want the count of TAGID in each grade based on the most recent date of (nearer to the date selected).

I tried ENDOFMONTH function but that not working. It's giving me the count of D which I don't want.

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Grade'[TAGID]), ENDOFMONTH('Grade[Date]))
```

Comment: Not clear what you want, is 30-11, based on grouping by month?

Comment: no it is the value that is selected in the filter. just a date, so whatever status each TAGID have as on 30-11-2018 should show in table.